# RDLC data is not changing

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

i am using rdlc to show a report dynamically based on the parameters.every thing works perfect on the first load .but after i change the parameter and load again even if the data table value is changed.rdlc is showing the previous result.what am i missing here

```
  private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportLoad();
        }

        private void reportLoad()
        {

            var fromdate=txtfromdate.Text;
            var todate=txttodate.Text;
            var accontHead=ComboaccHead.SelectedValue;
            var drawbankid=combodraw.SelectedValue;
            var noabankid=combonoa.SelectedValue;
            var type=ComboType.SelectedIndex;
            spParamCollection.Clear();
            spParamCollection.Add(new SPParams { Name = "@fromdate", Value =Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") });
            spParamCollection.Add(new SPParams { Name = "@toDate", Value = Convert.ToDateTime(todate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") });
            spParamCollection.Add(new SPParams { Name = "@AccountHead", Value = Convert.ToInt32(accontHead) });
            spParamCollection.Add(new SPParams { Name = "@drawbankid", Value = Convert.ToInt32(drawbankid) });
            spParamCollection.Add(new SPParams { Name = "@noabankid", Value = Convert.ToDecimal(noabankid) });
            spParamCollection.Add(new SPParams { Name = "@type", Value = Convert.ToDecimal(type) });
            DataTable dt = db.getDataUsingSP("CashBookReport", spParamCollection);

            reportViewer1.Clear();

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
          //  reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            reportViewer1.Visible = true;
            rds.Value = dt;
            rds.Name = "KWADataSet";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
           this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();




        }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the parameters for the report? In the snippet you posted you just build the `spParamCollection, but don't seem to do anything with it?

Comment: Set a break point in your code and look to see what values you are passing to the reportviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The btnsearch_Click is being fired after Page_Load and therefore the changes are not taking effect.

You need to place the report viewer reportViewer1 within an update panel and then update it at the end of reportLoad()

*Note: I simply added the =Globals!ExecutionTime expression to a text box within the .rdlc to test the refresh.*

For brevity sake, I have omitted the parameters.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
            WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reportLoad();
}

private void reportLoad()
{
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    // your datasource assignment here

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

    updatepanel1.Update();
}
```

Comment: reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); was enough for me..thanks mate !!